# What should be at /usr/local/bin on a new OSX

Tags: macos, darwin

I want to remove all programs which I don't need from `/usr/local/bin`.

What are the list of programs (folders / files), which should be on a new OSX.

Currently, I have the following list:

> `2to3 2to3-3.7
>   __pycache__ brew chardetect easy_install-3.7 f2py f2py3 f2py3.7 gdbm_dump
>   gdbm_load gdbmtool htop idle3 idle3.7 iptest iptest3 ipython
>   ipython3 jp.py jsonschema lzcat lzcmp lzdiff lzegrep lzfgrep lzgrep
>   lzless lzma lzmadec lzmainfo lzmore pcre-config pcregrep pcretest pip
>   pip3 pip3.7 plasma_store py.test pydoc3 pydoc3.7 pygmentize pyjwt
>   pytest python3 python3-config python3.7 python3.7-config python3.7m
>   python3.7m-config pyvenv pyvenv-3.7 rst2html.py rst2html4.py
>   rst2html5.py rst2latex.py rst2man.py rst2odt.py rst2odt_prepstyles.py
>   rst2pseudoxml.py rst2s5.py rst2xetex.py rst2xml.py rstpep2html.py subl
>   unlzma unxz virtualenv wheel3 xz xzcat xzcmp xzdec xzdiff xzegrep
>   xzfgrep xzgrep xzless xzmore zsh zsh-5.8`

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/593593/is-it-safe-to-delete-usr-local-for-a-clean-reinstall-of-misc-stuff-on-osx

Comment: As it is phrased, this is still a subjective question. Depending on install options there might be different things in that path.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like many (or most, or all) were installed by homebrew, so first try `brew list` to see which they are, then use `brew uninstall ...` to uninstall them.

If there's anything left after that, have a closer look.

Comment: It seems me, that there is some **python packages**, which I installed by mistakes globally instead of virtual environment. When I do `brew list`, I got very short list of programs: ```gdbm
htop
ncurses
openssl@1.1
pcre
python
readline
sqlite
xz
zsh```

Comment: Eh, I never understood the whole Anaconda stuff, and why it's better to install the same package multiple times, instead of just once globally. This eats up space like nothing if you need to do it a couple of times. How did you install the Python packages? With pip?

Comment: And the reason I am recommending first to find out what is installed is so that you are not surprised if these things go missing - as has been said in the comments, if you want to go back to a "pristine" Mac, you can just delete /usr/local.

Comment: There is no Anaconda, just pure python. All packages installed with pip only.
In case if I delete (for  "pristine")  *usr/local*, I assume, that I will have to reinstall: `brew, python, pip` and maybe some else?